Do I need to override constructor of base class?
I have a base class B, from which I will derive class D.  The only thing different in D is that I override a single method.
Do I have to override B's constructor in D, since all it will do is call B's constructor with the exact same parameters?  If I do not declare a constructor (or destructor) in D, will it just use B's? And if so, as of which version of C++ will it do so?

No, you don't need to override anything you inherit unlesss you need to modify it in the derived class.

The constructor is inherited automatically. Have you tried it?

With all due respect, a lot of the confusion here could be resolved by you simply sharing some code that shows what you would like to be able to do.

@Barmar I tried but compiler complains that "note: candidate: 'D::D()' (deleted)".  Do I have to tell the compiler the D constructor is public some how?  (See test created by RbMm for same result)

@RbMm Yes that seems to be key.  If no parameters, then the answer is NO.  But if with parameters, the answer is YES.

@TSG note, you can use using B::B; inside D to bring the constructor of B in scope, that's explicitly inheriting the constructor

@AhmedAEK  Can you give an example of that?  (I couldn't find one).  That might round out the answer nicely with the above, in case you want to post as answer

@TSG look into using-declaration, the part with Inheriting constructors

I discovered that when using namespaces, i need "Using Namespace::D::D"  The flip side of the same coin is the destructor (which that link doesn't address).  So I've added that to the question for completeness.  But seems to me I need to declare that even if it doesn't change from the base class

You typically should ask 1 question per post. Ask a separate question or search existing questions if you want an answer to an unrelated question.

@TSG "compiler complains that "note: candidate: 'D::D()' (deleted)"" - that kind of error usually suggests that D has a data member which the default generated constructor can't construct. Hard to say for sure in this case. Show some actual code you are having trouble with.

Force a Derived Class to use the Constructor of the Base Class

Constructors cannot be overriden.
They are there to intialize each class correctly.
The Derived class intializes it's variables.
The Base class initializes it's varibales.
You know which class you are constructing, so there is no need for a virtual constructor.
(But if you need to create a class making a decision during runtime, you need to know what a factory method is)
But deleting is more tricky (As you might be holding a pointer to Base class which was instantiated as a Derived class)
This is why destructors in a class with virtual methods should by default be virtual (there are exceptions to this rule - advanced topic).
class Base
{
private:
    int m_secret;

public:
    Base(int magic_number)
        : m_secret(magic_number)
    {}

    virtual int get_secret()
    {
        return m_secret;
    }

    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    int m_multiplier;

public:
    Derived(int magic_number, int multiplier)
        : Base(magic_number),
          m_multiplier(multiplier)
    {}

    int get_secret() override
    {
        return Base::get_secret() * m_multiplier;
    }

    ~Derived() override = default;


As noted in comments, add using B::B to your D class definition. This will generate constructors for D which do exactly the same as the corresponding constructors of B.
Constructors are not inherited (unlike normal methods). To inherit constructors, you need this special using declaration (it's technically not called inheritance, but the effect is the same).
